# VS2017 Not Loading Same DLL for Projects in Same Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have two projects under the same solution that both rely on `System.Net.Http' as a dependency. The strange thing is that both projects use different physical dll files, which is causing a runtime MissingMethodException error when trying to run unit tests.

library project uses:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll`

test project uses:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll`

Why are there two instances of the assembly and how can I force VS to use a specific instance? The csproj files do not specify a specific file path:
`<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />`

The only thing I can think of is I used the built in "Create Unit Tests" option when right-clicking the method in the library project. I'm guessing this loads a default set of references which does not match when you create a new project.

Comment: if the references are the same but in different folders, I would delete both references and create a Dependencies folder, re-add the .dll to that folder location and reference it from both projects in 1 single location vs both hope this makes sense to you..

Comment: You could try upgrading your MSTest dependencies via nuget.

Comment: I got around the issue by renaming the physical dll file that I did not want, forcing Visual Studio to choose the other dll. How does Visual Studio know where to look for assemblies? It seems that both paths are currently being searched and the problem is there are conflicting assemblies and sometimes Visual Studio chooses the other assembly unexpectedly, causing the error.